# windows update fails with error code 0x8024200E on Windows 2003 server

Tags: windows-server-2003, windows-update

I am able to automatically download updates on my Windows 2003 server machine but installation always fails for all the updates with the error code 0x8024200E. However, they work fine, if I download the individual updates manually & install. I have both the BITS and the automatic update services enabled and running with startup type set to automatic.

I am not sure what I am missing here. Any help on this issue is much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at the WindowsUpdate.log which should be in the root of your Windows directory (%systemroot%\windowsupdate.log). That may provide some more information beyond just the error 0x8024200E. The KB Articles [How to read the Windowsupdate.log file](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/902093/) and [How to troubleshoot common Windows Update, Microsoft Update, and Windows Server Update Services installation issues](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/906602) are worth reading.

Comment: How did you end up fixing the problem? Did you find some more information in the WindowsUpdate.log?

Answer (score 2):

One trick is to **use MBSA to reinstall the Windows Update Agent** software.

1. Download and install the *Microsoft Baseline Security Analyzer* on an adminstrative workstation or server somewhere. You should have this handy anyway if you're administering Windows Update - it's a good, light, non-invasive tool. As I write, the latest version is 2.1.1, available here;

   [Microsoft Baseline Security Analyzer 2.1.1 (for IT Professionals)](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=B1E76BBE-71DF-41E8-8B52-C871D012BA78&displaylang=en)
2. Run the tool and choose to *Scan one computer* - enter the name or IP of the problem server.
3. Deselect everything except the *Check for security updatess* options. Choose to *Configure computers for Microsoft Update and scanning prerequisites* - this will reinstall the Windows Update Agent software if it's corrupted. Choose to *Scan using assigned Windows Server Update Services(WSUS) servers only*, under *Advanced Update Services options:* - this will show you which patches are missing according to your WSUS approvals. If you're not running WSUS, use Microsoft Update.
4. Start scan.

If you have a client problem with the agent software, this may fix it.

Alternatively, choose *Scan using Microsoft Update only* under *Advanced Update Services options:* - this will show patch status according to Microsoft. It can be a useful spot-check to compare your WSUS approvals against Microsoft's master list on a few random servers every once in a while.

Answer (score 1):

One trick is to **delete the downloaded updates** and start again.

If an update is refusing to install, it's possible to stop the Automatic Updates service, delete everything under `%WINDIR%\SoftwareDistribution` (or at least `\Downloads\*` and `\Datastore\*`, start the Automatic Updates service again. Keep checking the tail of `%WINDIR%\WindowsUpdate.log` for progress - if nothing seems to be happening, try running `wuauclt /detectnow` at the command line.

Answer (score 0):

Running sfc /scannow fixed my issues with this - Seems like some system files were corrupt.

- Make sure to have the OS installation media on the CD drive or you can also change the SourcePath in the registry (HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Setup) to point to the Base directory OS installation files (Not the i386 directory and Network locations are allowed).
- on a command prompt run sfc /scannow (Should be able to do this from start->run sfc /scannow)
- Reboot and attempt to patch again.

Answer (score 0):

You can also download the latest Windows Update Agent [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/949104)

Answer (score 0):

Finally, after trying many solutions with no hope. I'm sharing the solution for all to benefit:

- Don't run Windows Update from "Start Menu" or from Control Panel.
- Instead open Internet Explorer, then --> Tools --> Windows Update "twice" to accept installation.